# Matlab animate background and line in same figure

Tags: matlab, animation, matlab-figure

I am trying to animate a line over a dynamic background at the same time, the problem is I cannot update both in the same plot. If I animate the background the lines don't appear. 
So the question is why? I was trying in different positions without success.

If you remove the part of the `imagesc`, there is no problem and the animation of the lines flow

```
for k = 1:numel(t)
    decay = rand;
    res = decay * background;
    imagesc(x,y,flip(res));
    hold on
    clearpoints(h);
    clearpoints(p);

    addpoints(p,[l,(cosO(k)],[0,cosO(k)]);
    addpoints(h,[r,(senO(k)],[0,senO(k)]);

    drawnow
    hold off
end
```

Fixed! Create a handler and modify CData inside of the loop:

```
imh = imagesc(x,y,flip(res));
for ...
    imh.CData = flip(res);

end
```

Comment: use `hold on` **before** the call to `imagesc`, or omit the `hold off` in the end, or use `imh=imagesc(...)` for `i=1` and then `imh.CData=flip(res)` for `i>1`.

Comment: Thanks, hold on/off strategy doesnt work, however creating the handler and modifying the CData it does!

Comment: @user2999345 Please convert you comment into an answer or the OP may do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The calls to `imagesc` overrun your plot. you can overcome this by only change the image matrix represented by `imagesc` (as `'CData'` property):

```
for k = 1:numel(t)
    decay = rand;
    res = decay * background;
    if k == 1
        imh = imagesc(x,y,flip(res));
    else
        imh.CData = flip(res);
        % or: set(imh, 'CData', flip(res) ); % in older MATLAB versions
    ...
end
```